# R - Generating frequency table from a table of pre-defined bins

Tags: r, frequency, binning

I need to generate a cumulative frequency plot of some bubble size data (I have >1000000 objects). In geology the way we do this is by using geometric binning.

I calculate the bins using the following method:

smallest object value aka 0.0015mm * 10^0.1 = upper limit of bin 1, the upper limit of each succcessive bin is generated by multiplying the lower limit by 10^0.1
Bin 1: 0.0015 - 0.001888388
Bin 2: 0.00188388 - 0.002377340

I tried writing a while loop to generate these as breakpoints in R but it wasnt working. So I generated my bins in Excel and now have a table with bins that range from my smallest object to my largest with bins sized appropriately.

What I now want to do is read this into R and use it to find the frequency of objects in each bin. I can't find how to do this - possibly because in most disciplines you dont set your bins like this.

I am fairly new to R so am trying to keep my code fairly simple.

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to use `?cut`. Here's an example with randomly generated data.

```
# generate data
set.seed(666)
runif(min=0, max=100, n=1000) -> x

# create arbitrary cutpoints (these should be replaced by the ones generated by your geometric method)
cutpoints <- c(0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 15, 20, 50, 90, 99, 99.01, 100)

table(cut(x, cutpoints))

  (0,1]      (1,10]     (10,11]     (11,12]     (12,15]     (15,20]
      9          92          13          10          27          45
(20,50]     (50,90]     (90,99]  (99,99.01] (99.01,100]
    310         399          87           0           8
```

Also note `include.lowest` parameter in `cut` defaults to FALSE:

> include.lowest: logical, indicating if an ‘x[i]’ equal to the lowest
>             (or highest, for ‘right = FALSE’) ‘breaks’ value should be
>             included.